# How do I add curses to cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, pdcurses

I'm having some problems with adding an external library to my project in CLion and everything I found regarding this topic didn't really get me any further.

I have these files added:

```
include/curses.h
include/panel.h
lib/pdcurses.lib
cmake-build-debug/pdcurses.dll
```

I've also added the files to my MinGW folder in case anybody is looking there... Yes, I'm lost.

How do my CMakeLists.txt does to have to look for this? Tried so much but since I really have no clue about cmake I can't get it to work.

currently it is looking like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(113_curses)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lpdcurses")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(113_curses ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
target_link_libraries(113_curses pdcurses.lib)
```

The errors

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable 113_curses.exe
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib\pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../..\pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib/pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../lib\pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../..\pdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
C:/Tools/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v5-rev1/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpdcurses
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\113_curses.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target '113_curses.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/113_curses.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [113_curses.exe] Error 1
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/113_curses.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You should be able to just use the `FindCurses` module... https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCurses.html

Comment: Like `find_package(Curses REQUIRED)`? Tried that one before: `Could NOT find Curses (missing: CURSES_LIBRARY)`

Comment: @sezi80 did you install ncurses?

Comment: I downloaded pdcurses for windows. As I said i did the files in the mentioned folders. In Visual Studio it is working when I add the libraries. I can just not get it working in CLion which I would prefer to use.

Comment: `How do my CMakeLists.txt does to have to look for this?` - According to build messages, CMake (linker, actually) finds your library, but treats it as incompatible. As you build your project from MinGW, you need **MinGW-compatible** version of ncurses, not a one for Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add:

```
include_directories(/path/to/curses/include)
```

Comment: isn't this what I did with `include_directories(${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` since i put the files in the project folder?

Comment: Those are the header files is YOUR project. You need to point the compiler to the location of the library headers as well.